# How to eagerly fetch all child collections?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I need a way to eagerly retrieve all child collections of all entities of a certain type using `NHibernate`.

I tried:

```
var myObjectList = SessionHolder.Current
    .CreateCriteria(typeof(MyObject))
    .SetFetchMode("Clients", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Locations", FetchMode.Eager)
    .SetFetchMode("Contracts", FetchMode.Eager)
    .List<MyObject>();
```

Query should had returned all MyObject instances from the DB with their collections eagerly loaded but it did not work as intended, instead it returned more objects than expected. I assume it has something to do with n+1 selects problem.

I found [this solution](http://ayende.com/blog/4367/eagerly-loading-entity-associations-efficiently-with-nhibernate) to retrieving the collections but I am currently restricted to using `NHibernate 1.2.1.4000` so I can't use Futures.

I did a lot of research before posting but couldn't find anything.

Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using distinct result transformer:

```
var myObjectList = 
    SessionHolder.Current
                 .CreateCriteria(typeof(MyObject))
                 .SetFetchMode("Clients", FetchMode.Eager)
                 .SetFetchMode("Locations", FetchMode.Eager)
                 .SetFetchMode("Contracts", FetchMode.Eager)
                 .SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())
                 .List<MyObject>();
```

Comment: I tested it, now it returns the right number of MyObject entities but the children are returned replicated, for example, for one instance of MyObject I might have in the returned list of Clients: Client1, Client1, Client1, Client2, Client2, Client2. Any ideea why that happens?

Comment: Could you please try it using HQL? Something like `SessionHolder.Current.CreateQuery("from MyObject o left join fetch o.Clients left join fetch o.Locations left join fetch o.Contracts").SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer()).List<MyObject>()`

Comment: gives the error message: `Cannot fetch multiple collections in a single query if one of them is a bag `

Comment: @RăzvanPanda: Sorry, I can't help you any further. It looks like the differences between the current and your extremely old version are too big.